# Limitations (drawbacks) of java programming language?

Tags: java

I am a beginner in java programming language, I have recently studied basic concepts of java programming language. I just want to know, What are the **limitations** of **Java** programming language in terms of memory management and other run time related issues.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: down voters, kindly mention your comments. Its difficult question for me. hopefully not for you.

Comment: I don't see any downvotes

Comment: +1 for your announcement. :)

Comment: You can go though this [article](http://www.jwz.org/doc/java.html), there are certain things  Jamie Zawinski pointed out.

Comment: people who want to close this question, kindly dare to put your comments.

Comment: I have downvoted because the question is too broad. For instance, it is not evident what kind of limitations you have in mind? Something like "the bytecode compiled for a method must not exceed 64k"?

Comment: Out of the back of my mind I remember reading that since Java uses a Garbage Collector, it can't be used for critical systems like rocket, life support as at a critical time the GC may kick in and try to do GC.

Comment: @Ingo, I have modified my quesiton.

Comment: @silverback Bloody GC..

Comment: @user2320537 That is still very broad.  For example the object memory alignment must be 8, 16 or 32 bytes.  This is still a very broad topic.  There is hundreds of command line parameters which relate to memory and you can discuss the significance of each one (or the fact there is so many)

Comment: The biggest limitation of Java and the JVM is that few developers understand what the JVM is really doing, or how to work around it's "features".  There are many myths about Java which get circulated, often because it is not clearly incorrect, or because this might have been true 10 - 15 years ago, but is not longer true.  You would be amazed how many questions there about libraries which were replaced in Java 1.2 in 1998 still come up.  Even more relate to things which changed in Java 5.0 release in 2004.

Comment: @silverback You can have predictable GC behavior if you opt for RTJS implementation.

Answer (score 4):

Java is OO programming language. Within that realm, considering static typing, there aren't much limitations. Java works well. At present JVM does not do tail call optimization, which can be considered a limitation. But that is limitation of the JVM, not the language. With Java 8 there are closures, and anonymous functions. The syntax is a bit ugly, but it's kind of ok. So we can't complain there. However, when comparing to functional languages (thinking Haskell), I miss array comprehensions, lazy evaluation the most.
The way in which Java approaches concurrency is using threads with shared data. We know that shared data can make parallel programming difficult. If Java has build in mechanisms for message passing like ZMQ or green threads (like Kilim) with no shared data, it would be cooler. But earlier on during the design phase they choose green threads, but later on moved to native ones for performance gains. Concurrency using STM (Software Transactional Memory) would be make great addition to `java.utils.concurrent` library. These aren't limitations per se, they can be added at a later point in time, using JSRs. But at present we do not have such mechanism.

Comment: You should need to read this article for know more : [**Bad features of Java**](http://geekonjava.blogspot.com/2015/06/bad-features-of-java.html)